# Check value of multiple foreach variables

Tags: php, foreach

I have a simple foreach function that loads a set of scripts in my website. The only issue is that 2 new scripts I've added need to be in a different folder location so my existing foreach doesn't work.

Is there a way that I can check of the value of the variable and, if it's one of the 2 new scripts, output a slightly different function?

Here is what I have right now;

```
$scripts = array(
    'modernizr',
    'browser-detect',
    'foundation.min',
    'functions',
    'rem',
    'custom'
);

foreach ($scripts as $script){
    wp_register_script($script, get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/'.$script.'.js#asyncload', 'jquery', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script($script);
}
```

Now the `foundation.min` and `functions` files are in `/js/` as oppose to `/assets/js/` so is there a way for me to check if the variable is either of these 2 and output a slightly different `register_script` and `enqueue_script` function?

Comment: if($script=='' || $script=='foundation.min')

Comment: I would suggest to add relative directory paths to your each script. This would be easy instead of dirtying your loop with conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more flexible by offering to specify the script as an array containing the script name and the folder if the folder if it is not the default one. Like this:

```
$scripts = array(
    'modernizr',
    'browser-detect',
    array('foundation.min', '/js'),
    'functions',
    'rem',
    'custom'
);

foreach ($scripts as $script){
    if(is_array($script)) {
        $scriptname = $script[0];
        $folder = $script[1];
    } else {
        $scriptname = $script;
        $folder = '/assets/js';
    }

    $path  = get_template_directory_uri();
    $path .= "$path/$script.js#asyncload";

    wp_register_script($scriptname, $path, 'jquery', '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script($scriptname);
}
```

Comment: This is outputting the theme directory (The `get_template_directory_uri` part twice and with the arrays it's just outputting Array.js (eg: http://mythemelocation.com/js/Array.js)

Answer (score 0):

Something such as this might be what you're looking for:

```
<?php

$scripts = array ('/assets/js/' => array ('modernizr','browser-detect','rem','custom'),
                      '/js/' => array ('foundation.min','functions'));

foreach ($scripts as $loc => $script) {
    foreach ($script as $name) {
       wp_register_script($name, get_template_directory_uri() . $loc.$name.'.js#asyncload', 'jquery', '', true);
       wp_enqueue_script($name);
    }
}

?>
```

It essentially groups the scripts into two different arrays depending on location. Then in the loop it's all handled accordingly.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that the scripts is executing at last, on the other hand the scripts `foundation.min` and `functions` file is being registered between the `/assets/js/` files.